# Use php-cli to start, restart, and stop apache 2.4 and mariadb

Tags: php, batch-file, windows-10, mariadb

Problem:
I am wanting to use php-cli scripts to quickly start, restart, or stop Apache 2.4 as well as MariaDB 10.5 on Windows 10. Several years ago, I did this while running Debian:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
system('sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start');
system('sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start');
```

I would then execute the file by typing something similar to 'php -f .server.start' where .server.start was the name of the file containing the above php code. I have had some luck getting this to work by opening a command line, changing directories to C:\Path\to\Apache24 and using

```
<?php
system('httpd -k start');
```

The issue with this is I still have to navigate to that directory to make this work. The purpose is then defeated as I could simply type httpd -k start || stop || restart. I am using this machine at home for a dev box. There are times when I am interrupted for lengthy spans of time and I feel that I need a simple and quick way to shutdown both Apache and MariaDB with a command or two while I am away from my desk.

Perhaps PHP isn't the best solution here? It's what I know and am comfortable with, though, if there are other methods, such as with a batch file, I would be willing to accept any comments/feedback/direction. I have scoured the web trying to get this task done.

Comment: Given how concise `https -k start` is, why bother with a wrapper script in any language? In any case, on Windows I would use a Powershell script. Just place it somewhere in your `PATH` so it's globally executable

Comment: Does this answer your question - [run powershell script from anywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15466499/run-powershell-script-from-anywhere)?

Comment: The thought behind this is that I regularly am called away from my desk. I dislike that I am leaving Apache and MariaDB running while I'm not at my keyboard. I do not want to have to open a cmd window, navigate to my apache directory and run a command to shut it down and then have to log into MariaDB and shut it down as well. I simply want one command to shut them both down in one shot, quickly and properly. In this way, I can avoid saying "just a minute" while I shut things down and simply run one command and go. I'll check out the powershell idea. Thanks for the comments